# Using Ajax To Update a Partial in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm a beginner programmer in Rails and I'm currently trying to create a simple form which takes a name, email, and phone number, and then when you click submit updates the page with what you have entered using Ajax.

i.e. if you enter User, user@example.com, and 555-555-555 into the text fields of the form and click submit, you should get

Name: User
Email: user@example.com
Phone Number: 555-555-555

I know this is a simple question but I'm not quite sure how to write the JavaScript to make it work.

Here's my code for the partial:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :remote => true) do |f| %>

Name: <div="Name"><%= f.text_field :name %></div>
Email: <div="Email"><%= f.text_field :email %></div><br/>
Phone Number: <div="Phone Number"><%= f.text_field :phone_number%></div><br/>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
end
end
```

In my create.js.erb file do I use the .update function to replace the text fields with the entered information or do I do something else??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you wrap your form in a div, you can replace its contents easily later:

```
<div id="theform">
<%= form_for(@user, :remote => true) do |f| %>

Name: <div="Name"><%= f.text_field :name %></div>
Email: <div="Email"><%= f.text_field :email %></div><br/>
Phone Number: <div="Phone Number"><%= f.text_field :phone_number%></div><br/>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
</div>
```

Then in your create.js.erb file:

```
$("#theform").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "users/user", locals: {user: @user}) %>");
```

And in your /app/views/users/_user.html.erb

```
Name: <%= user.name%> Email: <%= user.email%> Phone Number: <%= user.phone%>
```

Comment: Thanks so much--that worked! I'll have to next read up more on using Ajax within Rails but thanks again!! :)

Answer (score 1):

you got to you remote true on your form and make your controller respond to a js

View:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  Name: <div="Name"><%= f.text_field :name %></div>
  Email: <div="Email"><%= f.text_field :email %></div><br/>
  Phone Number: <div="Phone Number"><%= f.text_field :phone_number%></div><br/>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.save
    respond_to do |format|
      flash[:notice] = "saved successful"
      format.js # new.js.erb 
    end
  end
end
```

and create a new file named new.js.erb with the ajax code and use ruby embedded sintax as you please

```
$('div#my_id').html('<%= @user.name%> - <%= @user.phone %>');
$('div#notice').html('<%= flash[:notice] %>');
```